# Celery: apply_async wait for response

Tags: python, django, celery, apply-async

There are two services running in my application (`Srvice1`, `Servie2`).
A request is sent from the client to `Service1` and `Service1` calls a task as follows.

```
result = my_task.apply_async (kwargs = data)
```

And `my_task` calls an operation on server two:

```
@shared_task()
def my_task(** kwargs):
     return Server2.do_job(kwargs)
```

Similarly, `Service2` performs a series of celery tasks and eventually has to return the output to `Service1`.

Question:
How can I wait for the answer to be returned from server two?

I used `result.get()` to solve the problem but got no result.

Comment: How do you run your Celery worker? Give us the command line please. Could it be that you are sending to the wrong queue?

Comment: @DejanLekic `celery -A config.celery worker -l info -n worker_user`. celery.py is in the `config` folder.